# Update QJSON on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, updates, compiling

I currently have `libqjson-dev 0.7.1-6` installed on 12.04 via package manager. I need 0.8.0 in order to run an app I like. I have little experience compiling from source, less with cmake. I assume there's no backport.

Can someone please help me install 0.8.1 from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qjson/?source=dlp)?  I know that Ubuntu 13.10 comes with a higher version of QJSON. I'm hoping that they'll be no issues with QJSON 0.8 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks!

Comment: I was getting an error about missing qjson library and didn't realize that it was even available in package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'll try to install the 13.10 deb package by hand, dependencies of `libqjson0` are exactly the same for [0.7.1-6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libqjson0) (Ubuntu 12.04) and [0.8.1-2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libqjson0) (Ubuntu 13.10).

For amd64 arch, I'd download the following deb files:

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/saucy/amd64/libqjson-dev/download
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/saucy/amd64/libqjson0/download

and then run in the folder where you downloaded the deb files:

```
sudo dpkg -i libqjson0_0.8.1-2_amd64.deb libqjson-dev_0.8.1-2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Excellent answer - thank you! Is there a place online where I could have checked the dependencies of the lib?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the instructions on the "readme.md" file?

"For Unix/Linux/Mac:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=_preferred_path_ ..
make
make install
/sbin/ldconfig #if necessary
```

"